# Understanding and manipulating pointers to integer arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, array-pointer

I am having troubles with the following code:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  
fprintf(stdout,
        "a      : %lu\n"
        "*a     : %d\n"
        "&a     : %ld\n"
        "**(&a) : %d\n",
        (unsigned long int)a,
        *a,
        (unsigned long int)&a,
        **(&a)
);
```

Output:

```
a      : 140726063647232
*a     : 1
&a     : 140726063647232
**(&a) : 1
```

i know that `&a` is a pointer to the 1 D array. And `&a`'s type is `int (*)[4]`.
I am confused with how comes **`**(&a): 1`**.

Comment: You should use `%p` for pointers, not `%lu`.

Comment: If you are relative new to programming languages: in C an array is a pointer too. For basic language concepts, typing, some other language would probably be better. At least pedagogically.

Comment: `**(&a)` is 100% equivalent to `*a` and that's about it. It's just obfuscation - writing bad code on purpose.

Comment: @Lundin, The obfuscation is deliberate in order to teach one about dereferencing and referencing.

Comment: @AnshumanKumar Then why wasn't it written as either `**&a` or `*(*(&a))`? The former would be the cleanest and the latter could make sense if you expect the student not to grasp precedence/associativity. Something in between though?

Comment: Well, I am not the author of the code @Lundin. However, in the my first year at college, I had encountered such verbage in an introductory programming course.

Answer (score 1):

`&a` is a pointer to an array. `*p` gets what the pointer points to, so `*&a` gets the array, `a`.

An array treated as a pointer degenerates into a pointer to its first element, so `*a` is `1`.

Since `*&a` is just `a`, `**&a` is the same as `*a`, which is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is through the resulting type after each *address of* or *dereference* operation. A basic rule for array access is *Array-pointer* conversion. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) which applies on access to any array (subject to the 4 exceptions listed [3 in the C18 standard -- `_Alignof`is no longer listed]).

The key is to understand that an array, on access, is converted to a pointer to the first element (subject to limited exception - not relevant here). If you take the address of an array, the address is the *same* as that of the first element, but the **type** of pointer is completely *different*.

```
     a   - pointer to int
    &a   - pointer-to-array int[4], proper type: int (*)[4]
```

When you dereference `a`, you get the first element:

```
    *a   - int
```

Why? `*a` is short for the full derefernce operation with an offset of `0`, e.g.  `*(a + 0)` which is equivalent to `a[0]` in index notation.

When you dereference your *pointer-to-array* `int[4]`, you get your array back:

```
 *(&a)   - int[4] -> converted to pointer to first element.
```

which then, by operation of, [6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) is converted to a pointer to the first element. Dereference again and you get the first element:

```
**(&a)   - int
```

It's worth learning now as it will save you a lot of bewilderment later.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you whish to print an `address` yous hould use the `%p` conversion specifier for the `printf` or `fprintf` function.
2. on the other hand, printing `integer data type` with the same functions above, you should use the `%d` conversion specifier. then you can omit all the up-cast to `unsigned long int` data type.
3. `c arrays` decays to pointer of the same data type in your case (not in all cases arrays can `decays` to pointer). in your prints you have used this fact, e.g when dereference the array `*a`. this fact in c enable us to writhe the folowing statement:
   `int* a_ptr = a;`  AND `int* ptr = &a[0];`. now `a_ptr` and `ptr` are equal! pointing to the same address in memory.
4. printing `a` is like printing the `a_ptr` value and like printing the `ptr` value. which ends in printing the `&a[0]`.
5. printing `*a` is like printing *a_ptr and like printing `*ptr` and since `ptr = &a[0];` then , `*ptr` **==** `*&a[0]`**==**`a[0]` so in simple words its `a[0]` which is `1`.
6. priniting `&a`. now what is `&a` ? its a pointer to array of integeres! and to be more precised its a pointer to array of 4 integeres, which is `int (*)[4]` so when printing the address of a its like printing the dereference of `*(int (*)[4])` which is the the address of the array simple `a`. be aware that the data types are comletley different! `a` and `&a`!
7. printing `**(&a)` is the same as `*(*(int (*)[4]))` is the same as `*(a)` which is the same as `*(a+0)` which the same as `*ptr` which is : `a[0]` which is `1`.

fix the code snippet to be:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

fprintf(stdout,    /*you can use printf instead of fprintf(srdout,)*/
    "a      : %p\n"
    "*a     : %d\n"
    "&a     : %p\n"
    "**(&a) : %d\n",
       a,
      *a,
      &a,
   **(&a)
);
```